# How to write like mysql query which include result starting from search "keyword"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a search box and using a like query

```
select * 
from search_table 
where source like '%hola%';
```

I am getting result which include 'hola' word .

like

```
1   hola
2   this is hola
3  holascope
```

I just want to get the rows which start from 'hola'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to get the rows which start from 'hola'.

Remove starting wildcard `%`:

```
select * 
from search_table 
where source like 'hola%';
```

Output:

```
hola
holascope
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/378413)**</kbd>

If you have whitespaces you could `TRIM` them first:

```
SELECT * 
FROM search_table 
WHERE TRIM(source) LIKE 'hola%';
```